# C# - Convert Object to Array to get Data by Index

Tags: c#

I have a webservice that returns me an object with data

```
 object data = _wsUsuario.CarregarDadosUsuario(_view.Usuario);
```

This object, called `data`, returns me the following:
[0] 84
[1] Marcelo Camargo
[2] myemail@myprovider.com
[3] 2

If I try to do

```
MessageBox.Show(data[0]);
```

Then the compiler says me:

`Cannot apply indexing to an expression of type 'object'`. I searched and wonder if there is a way to convert this object of strings and integers to an array. Can you give me a hand?

Comment: If the underlying object is what you say it is, a simple cast should work `MessageBox.Show(((string[])data)[0]);`

Comment: What is `CarregarDadosUsuario` *actually typed* return - that is, what is the method signature? (I would hope it was an Array/IEnumerable/custom of some sort.) If it isn't `object`, you might be doing this The Hard Way by slopping it into such a variable. If it is unfortunately *typed* to return an object, what is the type of the *actual object* that is returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the data is an array of strings, then you would need to cast it accordingly:

```
object[] oData = (data as object[]) ?? new object[0];
```

This will *TRY* to cast to `object[]` but if it isn't castable, it will return null and the null coalescing operator `??` will return an empty object array instead.

Comment: I have both strings and integers.

Comment: Have updated my answer. You will have to cast the strings and integers in the array accordingly, of course.

Comment: And it will crash when indexing. Why not just not leave the result `null` and check for it? Edit: `ToString` would be semi-sufficient.

Comment: @leppie Could do, I suppose :) Either way he'll have to check for something

Answer (score 1):

An object **doesn't** have an indexer. An array **does**.

I think you downcasted the functions return type from a specific strong type object(some kind of array) into a basic 'object'.

What should happen:

```
// res should be an array
CarregarDadosUsuarioReturnType res = _wsUsuario.CarregarDadosUsuario(_view.Usuario);
MessageBox.Show(res[0]);
```

If, for any reason this service implicitly recieves an object simply cast this into:

```
object data = _wsUsuario.CarregarDadosUsuario(_view.Usuario);
var arr = data as ArrType[]; // where ArrType = the array type.
MessageBox.Show(arr[0]);
```